# It can't process the by clicking the spark-shell windows command script. What i do?

Tags: java, installation, windows-installer, apache-spark

In the Process of installing spark 1.0.0 by double clicking the bin/spark-shell windows command script file. Then opened one command prompt file and then immediately closed it self only. Are there any commands required to run this. Could you please tell me step by step process.

Comment: Try to run the script file from the command prompt

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to open a terminal. Theorically, you at least have the following on your machine :

- `cmd` (for sure)
- `powershell` (maybe not, if you're using Vista or less).

From there, you have two options :

- if you added `path_to_spark_folder\bin` to your `PATH` variable (see [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows) for more informations), you can run `spark-shell` as soon as the console is opened
- if you didn't, you'll have to go to `path_to_spark_folder\bin` yourself, using the `cd` command.

You now can run `spark-shell`.